# How to give different margin sizes for verso and recto pages in ConTeXt?

Tags: margins, context, double-sided, context-mkiv

I am creating a simple page layout for a book, which should have 1 cm margins along the top, bottom, and edge, but leave 3 cm in the middle margin, where the pages will be glued together.

```
 _____________________  _
|  ____    |    ____  | _ 1cm
| |    |   |   |    | |
| |    |   |   |    | |
| |____|   |   |____| | _
|__________|__________| _ 1cm

| |    |   |   |    | |
 1cm     3cm 3cm     1cm
```

I have thoroughly tested many options described in the new page design manual, but nothing worked as expected. This example is the closest I have gotten:

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A4, landscape]

\setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setuplayout[grid=yes, margin=10mm, leftmargin=5mm, width=103mm, rightmargin=5mm, backspace=30mm, topspace=10mm, top=5mm, header=0mm, height=190mm, footer=0mm, bottom=5mm, bottomspace=0mm, backspace=30mm]

\showframe
\starttext
    \input knuth
    \input knuth
    \input knuth
    \input knuth
\stoptext
```

- How can I ensure that verso pages have a 1 cm left margin and recto pages have 1 cm right margins?
- How can I ensure that the first page, table of contents, and all `\part`'s begin on a recto page?
- Why does my document appear to have 3 layers of frames around the text, as seen by `\showframe`, while the page design manual only has 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to enable doublesided layout. For some strange reason, this option is hidden in `\setuppagenumbering`.

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
```